# Configuring config files in bash

Tags: bash

My problem is as follows:

- I am directing the output of a print statement into a config file.
- When the print statement is run it returns multiple items.  When the
  items are output to the config
- I want to assign a variable name to each one so I can use them later.
- I want the assignment to be based on the variables used in the original print statement.

For example, say I have 4 categories of animals: cat, dog, horse and mouse. If the items that are printed correspond to the cat variable (used in the print statement) then I want those items to be assigned variable names of cat1, cat2, etc. This is so I can differentiate between the different variables types and use them effectively later.

Note: that I plan on only having the config filled with one of these 4 categories at a time and then each time the print statement is run I will overwrite the contents of the config file.

So my config file will look like this prior to assignment (after print statement has been executed)..

```
   whitecat
   blackcat

#or like this

   brownhorse
   greyhorse
```

And I want it to look like this after assignment..

```
   cat1="whitecat" 
   cat2="blackcat"

#or like this

   horse1="brownhorse"
   horse2="greyhorse"
```

## Here in as an example of what I want to do..

The print statement accesses a directory using a path `${MAINPATH}/${SUBPATH}` where `MAINPATH` is defined as `/home/jt8146` and `SUBPATH` is defined as either cat,dog,horse or mouse. It takes from based on the `SUBPATH` the information relating to that animal. i.e if the `SUBPATH` is defined as cat then it will input into the config file information like `whitecat` and `blackcat`

So the full path would look like `/home/jt8146/cat`

Once this information has been outputted to the config file I want the information `whitecat` and `blackcat` to be assigned to a variable. But rather than having to go into config file and type the assignment I want it to be executed automatically once the info. gets output to the config file.

So I was thinking I'd make a function that incorporates an `if`, `elif` statement i.e. `if SUBPATH = cat then do assignment cat1, cat2 to each element in the config file`

If the config file looks as follows before this if statement is executed

```
whitecat
blackcat
yellowcat
greencat
```

then `whitecat` would be assigned to variable `cat1`, `blackcat` to variable `cat2` and so on.

The `print` statement is a built in command from another application I am using and it retrieves information from a specified path. The `print` statement is working and the information is in the config file but not assigned and that is what I require help with.

My questions are:

1) How do you assign variables to the contents of a config once it has already been populated?

2) Is there a similar question on stack overflow someone could point me towards that answers my above question that I have failed to find?

Comment: `. config` .....

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk: This is the answer, but without any explanation, the PO (sorry, I mean jt8146) won't understand it.

Comment: Hi @PierreFrançois , are you able to elaborate?

Comment: Sure, I will do it.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you have a file named `config` that looks like this:

```
cat1="whitecat"
cat2="blackcat"
```

Now you want to have variables `cat1` and `cat2` that have `whitecat`
and `blackcat` values respectively.  You can do that by sourcing the config
file:

```
$ . config
$ echo $cat1
whitecat
$ echo $cat2
blackcat
```

(Notice that `$` here is a [command line
prompt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface#Command_prompt)
used to indicate start of a new line, not a part of the command).

`.` is as command in Bash and other shells that does *sourcing*, that
means reading the file given as an argument and executing every line in it as a shell command.

Comment: Hi, so this will take what is on the first line in the config and assign it the variable cat1?

Comment: It will take all lines, not just the first.

Comment: I've updated my question now to make it clearer.. this method will work for this ?

Comment: I don't understand what you want do.  Do you want to construct a config file first and then source it?

Comment: I want to run a print statement that will output ```whitecat and blackcat``` into a config i.e. using ```> config``` but ```whitecat``` and ```blackcat``` are now in this config file and they are not assigned to any variables. So I want to assign them to variables so that I can source them from the config file later. And I don't want this to be done manually i.e. just opening the config file after the print statement has been run and simply typing and assigning the variables one by one.. I want it to be done automatically based on what category they fall under e.g. dog/cat/horse etc.

Comment: `I want it to be done automatically based on what category they fall under e.g. dog/cat/horse etc.` - how do you know what category does the given value in the config file fall under?

Comment: Based on a variable ```$category``` used in the print statement to retrieve the elements ```whitecat``` and ```blackcat```

Comment: Edit your question to include this information. I still don't get your idea. Write a full example of what you want to do. I also don't know how do you want to *retrieve* anything with print (you meant `printf`?)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the first file you gave is called `config` and the category (`cat`, `horse`, etc...) is contained in the variable `$category`. In our example, the value of `$category` is `cat`.

First you will have to produce a file, lets say `"$category.config"` containing v.gr.

```
cat1="whitecat" 
cat2="blackcat"
```

Do it in the following way:

```
awk -v category="$category" '{print category""NR"=\""$0"\""}' config > "$category.config"
```

Now you want to make the variables defined in `"$category.config"` to be accessible to the current script, you have to *source* this file. This is possible using the `. "$category.config"` statement, which means that the content of `$category.config` must be sourced into the current script at the current point.

Demo:

```
echo before sourcing: cat1 = $cat1
. cat.config
echo after sourcing: cat1 = $cat1
```

will produce next output:

```
before sourcing: cat1 = 
after sourcing: cat1 = whitecat
```

Instead of `. cat.config`, I could have issued `. "$category.config"`.

Comment: Will this method work for my updated question to make things clearer?

Comment: This is another question. It had been better to post a new question in order not to break the whole logic of the post. Anyway, I will modify my answer.

Comment: What do you mean when you say ```v.gr.```

Comment: The abbreviation v.gr. (= verbi gratia) means "for example". See http://acronymsandslang.com/definition/7776153/V.G.%2C+V.GR.-meaning.html